# How can I tell if I have x64 or 32bit Solaris10

Tags: solaris-10

I have Solaris10 running in VMPlayer how can I find out if this is a 64bit or 32bit Solaris10?

Comment: $ cat /etc/release
                    `Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10x_u11wos_24a X86`

Answer (score 12):

May be

```
/usr/bin/isainfo -kv
64-bit sparcv9 kernel modules
```

Works on sparc at least !!

Comment: Thank you very much!that works on my Solaris10 image and proves it is a 64bit image.

Comment: You're welcome. You might consider ticking the answer to make it official then ;-)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, Thx for the link

Answer (score -1):

Use 'prtconf' at the console. It will give you system configuration.